# Spring mvc cannot autowire dao classes in junit tests

Tags: spring-mvc, junit4

I have a spring mvc web application configured using javaconfig and I am trying to autowire my dao classes on the junit test class and I am using @EnableWebMvc for the servlet config, but it gives me the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.jahidul.islam.test.tests.TestJunit': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'strengthDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.jahidul.islam.dao.StrengthDao' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
```

My Test Class which is used for the junit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextHierarchy({
    @ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.class),
    @ContextConfiguration(classes=WebAppInitializer.class)
})
public class TestJunit {

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    StrengthDao strengthDao;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(strengthDao.getStrength(1));
    }

}
```

My WebAppInitializer Class which initializes all the configurations:

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {WebAppBeanConfig.class, WebAppDaoConfig.class, WebAppServiceConfig.class, WebSecurityConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {WebAppServletConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return new Filter[]{new HiddenHttpMethodFilter()};
    }

    @Override
    protected DispatcherServlet createDispatcherServlet(WebApplicationContext servletAppContext) {
        final DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = (DispatcherServlet) super.createDispatcherServlet(servletAppContext);
        dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
        return dispatcherServlet;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active", "production");
    }

}
```

My Dao Class which is used to fetch data from mysql database using hibernate:

```
@Component("strengthDao")
@Transactional
public class StrengthDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Session session() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public List<Strength> getAllStrengths(int perPage, int offset) {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = session().getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Strength> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Strength.class);
        Root<Strength> root = criteriaQuery.from(Strength.class);
        criteriaQuery.select(root);
        return (List<Strength>) session().createQuery(criteriaQuery).setFirstResult(offset).setMaxResults(perPage).getResultList();
    }

    public long strengthCount() {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = session().getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Long> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
        Root<Strength> root = criteriaQuery.from(Strength.class);
        criteriaQuery.select(builder.count(root));
        return (long) session().createQuery(criteriaQuery).getSingleResult();
    }

    public void saveOrUpdateStrength(Strength strength) {
        session().saveOrUpdate(strength);
    }

    public Strength getStrength(int id) {
        return (Strength) session().get(Strength.class, id);
    }

    public void deleteStrength(Strength strength) {
        session().delete(strength);
    }

}
```

Comment: `@Repository(value = "strengthDao")` try adding on your `StrengthDao` class

Comment: It doesn't solve my issue. @NishanDhungana

Answer (score 0):

Either add componentScan annotation to TestJunit class to auto detect @Repository components.
Or create a java config bean in TestJunit class using @Bean annotation like

```
@Bean 
public StrengthDao StrengthDao(){
  return new StrengthDao ();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But neither of these solve my issue. @Ramesh Fadatare

Comment: Yes, I have. @Ramesh Fadatare